# XML Structure from ontology

Tags: xml, ontology

Database A contains list of Football clubs and Cricket Clubs for every city and their stadiums.I have written a vague XML structure for the given ontology.But there is error in the structure.I am not able to find the error in the XML.Can anybody point out the error in this?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<City>
<Name>London</Name>

    <Football_clubs>
        <club_details>
            <name>Chelsea FC</name>
            <stadium>Stamford Bridge</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Fulham</name>
            <stadium>Craven Cottage</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Spurs</name>
            <stadium>WHL</stadium>
        </club_details>
    </Football_clubs>
    <Cricket_Clubs>
        <club_details>
            <name>Yorkshire</name>
            <stadium>XYZ</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Leicetshire</name>
            <stadium>ABC</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Surrey</name>
            <stadium>GHI</stadium>
        </club_details>
    </Cricket_Clubs>


 </City>


 <City>
<Name>Manchester</Name>

    <Football_clubs>
        <club_details>
            <name>Manchester Utd</name>
            <stadium>Old Trafford</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Manchester City</name>
            <stadium>Maine Road</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Bolton</name>
            <stadium>SDF</stadium>
        </club_details>
    </Football_clubs>
    <Cricket_Clubs>
        <club_details>
            <name>Yorkshire</name>
            <stadium>XYZ</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Leicetshire</name>
            <stadium>ABC</stadium>
        </club_details>
        <club_details>
            <name>Surrey</name>
            <stadium>GHI</stadium>
        </club_details>
    </Cricket_Clubs>


  </City>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a root element? There has to be one and just one in an XML document and all I can see are multiple `City` tags wrapped with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

definitely missing the root element:

"Each XML document has exactly one single root element. This element is also known as the document element. It encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements."  - wiki

should be:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<cities>
    <city>
        ...contents
    </city>
    <city>
        ...contents
    </city>
</cities>
```